# Local group membership not updated until after relogin

Tags: windows

Whenever I add a user to a local user group, the membership does not seem to be reflected until after I reboot.

**EDIT** As noted in comments, this is actually refreshed with logoff/login, not reboot.

What can I do to force a refresh of whatever seems to be getting refreshed on reboot?

This is on Windows 10.

Comment: The access token of a new logon will have the group. If this is the session user, you'll have to log off (end the session) and log back on. You shouldn't have to reboot.

Comment: The accepted answer here works, but is a bit intrusive. https://serverfault.com/questions/336250/how-do-you-force-an-update-to-a-users-group-membership-in-windows-7

Comment: Using another logon via the secondary logon service (i.e. runas.exe, `CreateProcessWithLogonW`, etc) creates a messy situation in which programs are using up to four different access tokens -- standard and elevated for each logon session. This will be annoying for per-logon devices/drives. The session access token from [`WTSQueryUserToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsqueryusertoken) will still be the old access token, so services that start programs in the session, such as Task Scheduler, will probably still use the old token.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to automate the process described in [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/336250/how-do-you-force-an-update-to-a-users-group-membership-in-windows-7) in C#.

```
using (Process killProcess = new Process())
{
    killProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "taskkill.exe";
    killProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/F /IM explorer.exe /FI \"USERNAME eq {Environment.UserDomainName}\\{Environment.UserName}\"";
    killProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    killProcess.Start();
    killProcess.WaitForExit();
}

using (Process startProcess = new Process())
{
    startProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer.exe";
    startProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
    startProcess.StartInfo.UserName = Environment.UserName;
    startProcess.StartInfo.Domain = Environment.UserDomainName;

    // get password
    SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
    Console.Write("Password: ");
    char c;
    do
    {
        c = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar;
        if (c != (char)13)
        {
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        }
    } while (c != (char)13);
    securePassword.MakeReadOnly();

    startProcess.StartInfo.Password = securePassword;
    startProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startProcess.Start();
}
```